# Is it ok to have excess elements in array initializer?

Tags: c, arrays

Usually when we initialize an array, we would probably do:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

But is it ok to explicitly limit the length of the array as below? :

```
int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Despite some warnings from the compiler, the executable doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to take heed of warnings. But the compiler is gracious enough to ignore your ramblings on extra elements. However I feel this is sloppy programming.

Comment: What is the motivation for doing is? I don't see any practical use for it, why does it matter?

Comment: @aaronman, OP may want to limit the included items based on a macro or something

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: @perreal the compiler already warns you and there is no reason to do it anyway, so why do it

Comment: @AnoopssGolden It must be `gcc`.

Comment: If it is done is IDE like Turbo C++ or something like that it will show error

Comment: Worst case is you overwrite some memory with garbage values (which is bad and can break other stuff!)

Comment: @AnoopssGolden, I'm using GCC for windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not OK. From C99, 6.7.8.2:

> Constraints
>
> 1. No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

In my read, this means that providing excess initializer elements is a **constraint violation,** so it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: To clarify do you mean that in the example above arr[5] and above is defined behavior but arr[4] and below is undefined?

Comment: @Pacerier If I understand the Standard correctly, then yes, exactly.