# Can we assign longer string to array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

After reading online, I have come to know that following are undefined behaviors in C:

1. Accessing element outside array

   ```
   char a2[4] = {'g','e','e','k','s'}; 
   printf("a2[4]:%d,%c\n",a2[4],a2[4]); //last index of a2 is 3
                                        //so a2[4] is undefined
   ```
2. Having excess elements in array intializing list

   ```
   int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; //size of arr is 3, but we specified 5 elements
                                 //undefined behavior
   ```

I want to ask if behavior in the following related scenario's involving pointers and strings are undefined or not:

1. Assigning longer string to character array:

   ```
   char arr[5] = "geeks"; //"geeks" contains 6 characters including `\0`
                          //but arr has size 5
   ```
2. Accessing farther index with pointer.

   ```
   char * arrptr = arr; //variable arr from point 1
   ```

   or

   ```
   char * arrptr = "geeks";
   ```

   and then doing

   ```
   printf("%c",arrptr[7]);
   ```

   I believe this must be surely undefined as index 7 does not belong to anything in current context.

Can anyone clarify this or point me to the relevant section in C standard?

Comment: Hmm ... we're not talking about *assignment* here (you cannot assign values to arrays); we're talking about *initialization*. `char arr7[4] = "foo";` is initialization; `arr7 = "foo";` is **illegal** assignment;

Comment: last index of a2 is 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char arr1[5] = "geeks"; // extra '\0': ok
char arr2[4] = "geeks"; // extra 's' and '\0': error
```

Initialization of char arrays with `'\0'` as one extra element is a special case. See [C11 6.7.9p14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14) (emphasis is mine)

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

Comment: ohhh does that means `char arr[5] = "geeks";` is not UB, but `char arr[4] = "geeks";` is UB?

Comment: yes, the special case applies only to the terminating null character (edited my answer to emphasize it too)

Comment: Nope, I believe this shouldnt be ok: `char arr1[5] = "geeks"; // extra '\0': ok`. The standard says "if there is room or if the array is of unknown size". I guess there is not enough room (all five locations are occupied by `geeks` with none left for `\0`), so still UB, right?

Comment: It's not UB: the resulting array is not a string though. As well as arrays of `int`, of `double`, of anything really; arrays of char are not special. They may be used in a particular way (as a string) if one of their elements is the `'\0'`.

Comment: ok so that does means, if enough room is there, we will also copy `\0` to array, but if not there, we will ignore it. But room should be there for all non-`\0` characters.

Comment: Correct! `char arr1[6] = "aaa";` makes arr1[0 to 2] = a; arr1[3 to 5] = '\0'; and `arr1` can be used as a string. If you later change `arr1[3] = arr1[4] = arr1[5] = 'a';` it can no longer be used as a string, but it's still a perfectly legal array of char.

Answer (score 1):

1. `char arr[5] = "geeks";  // ok`

This statement itself is not UB. It simply initialise a char array (instead of string).

But when you start using it with something like `printf` it will become a UB:

```
`printf("%s", arr);  // UB`
```

2. For your point 2) it's certainly UB because you are accessing out-of-bound

   `printf("%c",arrptr[7]);  // UB`

Comment: yup, but `char a2[4] = {'g','e','e','k','s'};` us UB, right?

Comment: @anir, yes it's UB, artm: it compiles if you don't specify `-Werror` flag

Comment: But then why such different behavior for array initializer and string initializer? That is between `char arr1[5] = "geeks";` and `char arr2[4]= {'g','e','e','k','s'};`? Former is not UB but later is. ***Why*** such behavior is defined? Whats so bad in `{'g','e','e','k','s'}` than in `"geeks"`?

Comment: @anir, because the first case is an array of `char`s  and in the second one you are overloading the array,  you asign more data than requested and in consequence you can overwrite another data segment

Comment: @KeineLust Didnt get at all. **(1)** "first case is an array of `char`s". This one: `arr1[5] = "geeks";` **(2)** "in the second one you are overloading the array". In this one: `char arr2[4]= {'g','e','e','k','s'};` ? **(3)** If answer to (2) is yes, then whats "array overloading"? Heard this term first time in C. **(4)** In both rvalue is longer than lvalue. `"geeks"` is of length 6 including NULL `\0`, but `arr1` is of size 5. Similarly `{'g','e','e','k','s'}` is of size 5, but `arr2` is of size 4. So shouldnt both be UB?

Comment: @pmg I know and thats not the point. In both rvalue is longer than lvalue. `"geeks"` is of length 6 including NULL `\0`, but `arr1` is of size 5. Similarly `{'g','e','e','k','s'}` is of size 5, but `arr2` is of size 4. So shouldnt both be UB?